# How do I control what authenticated users can see in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, authentication, view

Trying to hide a view to create a restaurant from anyone other than a restaurant Owner.

Used examples shown using groups and testing whether a user is in that group or not but nothing seems to work.

## views.py

```
def is_owner(user):
    if user.objects.filter(name="Owner").exists():
        return True

class CreateRestaurantView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CreateRestaurantForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'signup.html'

@login_required
def create_restaurant(request):
    if is_owner == True:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = CreateRestaurantForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                restaurant = form.save(commit=False)
                restaurant.Restaurant_Owner = request.user
                restaurant.save()
                return redirect('restaurant_list')
        else:
            form = CreateRestaurantForm()
        return render(request, 'create_restaurant.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html')
```

## forms.py

## signup form for Owners

```
class OwnerCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text=_("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username",)

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(OwnerCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])

        if commit:
            user.save()
            group = Group.objects.get(name='Owner')
            user.groups.add(group)

        return user
```

I'm trying to get the view to show the create_restaurant form when a user belongs to the "Owner" group but the function to test (is_owner) does not work and is always false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are defined **`is_owner`** as ***function***, so, you should call it as **`is_owner(any_user_object)`**
Second thing is, to search over the **`Group`**, it should be as

```
user.groups.filter(name="Owner").exists()
```

---

**code snippet**

```
def is_owner(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name="Owner").exists()


@login_required
def create_restaurant(request):
    if is_owner(request.user) == True:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = CreateRestaurantForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                restaurant = form.save(commit=False)
                restaurant.Restaurant_Owner = request.user
                restaurant.save()
                return redirect('restaurant_list')
        else:
            form = CreateRestaurantForm()
        return render(request, 'create_restaurant.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html')
```

---

### UPDATE-1

change the **`save()`** method of **`OwnerCreationForm`** as below

```
class OwnerCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # your other code

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(OwnerCreationForm, self).save(commit=True)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if not user.groups.filter(name="Owner").exists():
            group = Group.objects.get(name='Owner')
            user.groups.add(group)
        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: I think it should be `user.groups.filter(...)` :)

Comment: I made these changes and still have the issue of the function not returning True. The else condition is accessed and the user within the Group "Owner" is rerouted to the home page.

Comment: Are you sure that the logged-in user belongs to the **Owner** group?

Comment: and What is the result of **`print(list(request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)))`** ?

Comment: I logged in as an Admin and it seems that when you create a new user as an Owner it doesn't actually add them to that group. After adding them to the group the logic functions correctly. So the Sign up form (OwnerCreationForm) seems to be the issue.

Comment: Check my **`UPDATE-1`** section

Comment: Thank you so much this has fixed my issue and it all works properly!!